# Why can another user delete my question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

I get it if the question is bad or whatever then users can vote to close it, but to delete it?

This negatively impacts my standing. I can become banned from ever asking questions because others delete my questions... What then?

Comment: Pleas [edit] your question to include some examples that we can discuss...

Comment: Note that, unless a moderator handles it, it takes _at least_ 3 votes to delete for other users to delete your post. As the score of your post rises (unless I'm thinking of something else) it takes _more_ votes to delete said post. So it's not like I could single-handedly say "This meta question sucks!", downvote it, and delete it. Said users _also_ have to have at least 10k reputation to be able to vote to delete. So it's not like every single user can do so.

Comment: Which question of you did I delete? Do you have a link to it, it might still be in recent deleted questions at the bottom of your question list in your profile. That would enable me to see if I made a mistake.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, I'm pretty sure that, unless the voters have 20k rep, the question has to be closed (and I think it has to be closed for a couple days) before it can be deleted. If your question is deleted and a 10k+ rep user has a link, they can vote to undelete if they feel the deletion was incorrect. Deletion is a soft-delete here- The post still exists, it's just hidden to most users.

Comment: @Kendra It needs to be closed for 2 days to be eligible for deletion by <20k users, to be exact. In addition to what you said, every 10k+ user has access to a list of recently deleted questions, as well as questions with delete/undelete votes on them. So even if a question gets deleted and nobody has a link to it, it will still show up in the 10k+ tools and get a chance at undeletion.

Comment: @Kendra It takes 10k, not 20k, rep to vote to delete a question.  Questions with a score of -3 or less can have delete votes cast any time they're closed, posts with a higher score can only have delete votes cast 2 days after they've been closed.  Having 20k rep doesn't remove that restriction.

Comment: @Servy I think you may have ever so slightly misread my last comment- I meant that users with 10k rep, but not up to 20k yet, have a time limit before they can vote to delete after the question is closed. I stated in the first comment that 10k rep is needed to vote to delete at all. (The -3 or less part, however, I had missed as I didn't know that. Or that the question still needs to be closed.)

Answer (score 15):

Your most recent question was deleted by a *site moderator*. In fact, none of your other recently deleted questions were deleted by regular community members; they all were deleted either by yourself or by automatic processes.

[Site moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) have specific responsibilities, and with those responsibilities, certain powers regular users do not have. This includes the power to delete posts outright.

Regular users can delete questions too, but this is limited to [users with 10.000 points or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) and requires *at least* 3 votes from separate users. 10k users have to wait at least 2 days before they can vote, your question was not old enough to qualify for such voting. At 20k users gain the right to [vote to delete immediately if the question score is -3 or lower](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

We delete some questions to keep the site clean. Your question was off-topic (asking for a tutorial) and the commenting on the post was getting out of hand; your tone specifically. The site moderator deleted the post to head off any further issues.

Comment: @Ortund: yet we expect you to [adhere to our behaviour policy](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), at all times. Your question was specifically off-topic, see the [help/on-topic]; the community was merely doing exactly what we ask them to do: vote to close the question.

Comment: At 1.7k rep, YOU are a more experienced user.  You were supposed to not ask the question at all, it is clearly laid out that questions asking for recommendations are not allowed in any way shape or form.   Just because something is a question does not mean that it can be asked here.

Answer (score 10):

Others can delete your question because either:

- They're a user with [that associated privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (and three of them must act on the question), or
- They're a [moderator](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and they're deleting it based on a specific moderator action.

There are actions that will also delete questions automatically without either group's intervention, such as spam.

**Why allow it?**  It's one way to maintain high Q&A standards, and ensure that questions that really don't belong here don't stick around for long.

The main motivation here is:  don't ask questions that are blatantly off-topic, too broad, or are just offensive (although I doubt that you would).  Since you've contributed a fair amount here, I would *imagine* that someone would chat with you before you reached the danger zone.

Comment: Nobody chatted with me the last time I reached this so-called "danger zone" and my account was totally banned from asking questions for a couple of days... Also, the problem with this whole Q&A standards thing is that when you're getting into something new (like I am) and you're in way over your head (like I am), you don't know how to make a "quality" question... So because of that this community punishes you and leaves you with no help when you have no idea how to proceed... Nice hey?

Comment: So don't ask the question. If you can't make it a quality question, don't ask it. do more research instead. Try a solution on your own instead. This isn't the catch-all for any kind of question, it has to be on topic and objectively answerable.

Answer (score -5):

This is the way Stack Overflow works. We've all been beginners and I also started with 1-rep. My [very first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853237/retrieving-width-and-heightinformation-from-img-loaded-through-html) here has been pretty well received (with two up-votes).

So lack of knowledge in a field doesn't mean you lack of knowledge of how Stack Overflow works and its quality standards.

Feel free to read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Feel free to look around for [meta questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/popular/questions?show=today&sort=hot) when you are in doubt.

Comment: It might be the right sentiment but I'm not sure if this fully addresses the question of the OP.

Comment: @rene: You are surely right. This was my first answer on meta :)

Comment: OK, well let me down vote it then for not useful, OK?

Comment: @rene: That's the game!

Comment: Oh, you're not going to post on meta about this down vote? Or serial down vote all my meta posts? Or flag for a moderator to get me suspended? This will be an easy night for me then ;)

Comment: @rene: No, I just get the message here... I won't be posting any more answers on meta! ;-)

Comment: That was a short-lived experience then :D